# get the sharedPreferences's update in another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
confbutton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // get the ip address
    String ipAddress = editTextIPAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    // get the port number
    String portNumber = editTextPortNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    // save the IP address and port for the next time the app is used
    editor.putString(PREF_IP, ipAddress); // set the ip address value to save
    editor.putString(PREF_PORT, portNumber); // set the port number to save
    editor.commit(); // save the IP and PORT

    // get the IP address and port number from the last time the user used the app,
    // put an empty string "" is this is the first time.
    editTextIPAddress.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_IP, ""));
    editTextPortNumber.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_PORT, ""));

    onBackPressed();}
});
```

I wrote this in a Settings Activity to get the ip address and the port number. Then i called the SharedPreferences in the Main Activity using this:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HTTP_HELPER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ipAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_IP, ipAddress);
portNumber = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_PORT, portNumber);
displayText.setText(ipAddress);
```

I used the `displayText.setText(ipAddress)`to see if i got it or not. It worked but it only gives me the last `SharedPreferences` if i change it in the Settings Activity and go buck to the Main Activity it doesn't change until i kill the app and reopen it again.

I tried to do this :

```
SettingsButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.ela_hidri.myremote.SettingsActivity");
    startActivity(intent2);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HTTP_HELPER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ipAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_IP, ipAddress);
    portNumber = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_PORT, portNumber);
    displayText.setText(ipAddress);
}});
```

It does change the text but only if i click the button `Settings`.

I want for it to change every time i change it in the Settings Activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i read a SharedPreferences from another activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959200/how-can-i-read-a-sharedpreferences-from-another-activity)

Comment: As I already told you in your previous question, `You can access your SharedPreferences from everywhere inside your app`.

Comment: yes i did that .. but whene i update  the ip adress it won't change

Comment: You must use **put**String(), if you want to write to your SharedPreferences. You are using **get**String(), instead.

Comment: Shared Preferences is a tried and tested approach, there is something wrong with your logic - if your code for getting the `ipAddress` is in `onCreate()` then it will only get called when the activity is destroyed and recreated, when you go to the settings again your Actiivity is not destoyed and in a pause state - put the logic in `onResume()`

Comment: i want to save data only if i clicked the button  and i used on Resume and it works  thnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `onResume` function of your Main Activity. When you change the Ip Address and the Port from Settings Activity - you're saving it in the SharedPreferences - right?

Now when you come back to the `MainActivity`, you need to put the following codes inside your `onResume` function of the `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Get the Sharedpreferences here
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HTTP_HELPER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ipAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_IP, ipAddress);
    portNumber = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_PORT, portNumber);
    displayText.setText(ipAddress);
}
```

Hope this will do the trick for you.

Comment: ha, see comment above .. beat me to it by 5 seconds! :)

Comment: haha... I was editting and answering the question in that time. The question was a mess. :P